# how mix a var in js to a code of ruby on rails in a view

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, web, model-view-controller

i want something like this:

[image]

[image]

polo and rere are country

all i need is get the information of what country the user want to be moderate, but i can not take the information because i can t mix code on ruby on rails and code html, js so i really don t know what can i do?

i search for a lo of foros but i can t find a code that let me mix both kind of code to do somthing like this

```
<%=Country.find(document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML)%>
```

here are my html code:

```
<label for="petition">do your petition to be moderator of some country:</label>

<div class="select you country moderate">
<button id="btn1" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">select country</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <% Country.all.each do |country| %>

        <button onclick=myFunction2("<%= country.name %>","<%= country.id %>") ><%= country.name %></button>

    <%end%>
  </div>
</div>


<form action="/" >

    <button name="petition" value="<%=Country.find(document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML)%>" type="submit">ask for be moderator</button>

</form>
```

and here js code:

```
<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {

    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");

}
function myFunction2(country_choose,id_country) {
    document.getElementById("btn1").innerHTML=country_choose
        var x = (id_country);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x; 
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and here i put the controller:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_welcome, only: [:show]
  protect_from_forgery :except => :receive_guest
  helper_method :current_or_guest_user

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @countries=Country.all




    puts params[:petition]
end
```

error of the view:

```
undefined local variable or method `document' for #<#<Class:0x00005616768bb6f8>:0x00007f12e8e48d90>

Extracted source (around line #67):


<form action="/" >

    <button name="petition" value="<%=Country.find(document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML)%>" type="submit">ask for be moderator</button>

</form>
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to read about AJAX. You have to read the value when the user selects it, do an AJAX request to your server, render a response and process that response clientside.

Comment: but there is not way to make it with the form that i need it?

Comment: ruby code is processed and then rendered, it's a complete different context. I insist, read about AJAX, you are asking to do something that cannot be done and the solution is to use async requests to fetch the values from the server after the user does something clientside.

Comment: What you CAN do, is to have a button with type submit for each country inside the actual form element, you can send different values depending on what button is clicked without the need of javacsript. You can also use radio buttons instead of button. You can't do what your are asking the way you want to do it.